# Oracle Apex RAS is not supported on this system

Tags: oracle, apex

one of my applications button stopped working on production, while it was working before, and it's still working on development server,
after enabling the debug mode I can see the following error, please support

---

```
RAS is not supported on this system

APEX Version=20.2.0.00.20

SID=1139

USER=APEX_PUBLIC_USER

INSTANCE=1

POST http://192.168.40.78:8010/ords

REMOTE_ADDR=192.168.235.18

REMOTE_USER=APEX_PUBLIC_USER

APEX_LISTENER_VERSION=19.2.0.r1991647

REFERER=http://192.168.40.78:8010/ords/apex_iha/r/store-employee-evaluation/login?session=3445169994675

CGI: PATH_INFO = /wwv_flow.accept
```

---

Notes:

- My DB version is: 11.2.0.4.0

  The code in the button working fine if I try to execute directly on
  DB level

  When login internal and checking instance security setting I can see
  any parameter related to real application security

This button is doing the following: [Button Code](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AoD0E5_W25Swk94f7pvACuuB0StS6Q?e=Txtx2D)

Thanks ...

Comment: Which Oracle DB version and edition are the development and production servers?

Comment: Button issue resolved, it was not related to that RAS error, it was data issue, now my application is working fine just I am receiving the RAS in log file which is not impacting the application anymore, thanks ....